# Java 8 Lambda on Primitive Boolean

Tags: lambda, java-8

How do I make the following example work?

```
Boolean persistence =  Arrays.asList(new boolean[]{true, false})
                             .stream()
                             .filter(b -> b)
                             .findFirst().orElse(false);
```

It works just fine when I replace `boolean` with `Boolean`.

Comment: you cannot create a stream of primitive booleans. btw the current example can be simplified to `Stream.of(true, false)
                                     .anyMatch(e -> e);` though it's probably simpler to do `boolean persistence = true;`

Comment: I am assuming the array of booleans to `Arrays.asList` is dynamic i.e. you don't know the values beforehand. in that case, you'll need to proceed with using `Boolean` instead of `boolean`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot create a `Stream` of primitive booleans, this is the most efficient approach that does what you want.

```
boolean[] myArray = new boolean[]{ true, false };
boolean result = IntStream.range(0, myArray.length)
                          .anyMatch(index -> myArray[index]);
```

or you can replace the `anyMatch` with your approach of `filter` -`findFirst` if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I needed.